# Remove parentheses and commas from NSArray output

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I am using the following code snippet for an app I'm working on to print a list of words on the iPhone screen:

```
    NSString *labelText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [self.dictionary selectList]];
//creates a string list from an NSDictionary key with a value of an NSArray that has NSString objects in it
    self.listLabel.text = labelText;
//displays list in label
```

The listed words are displayed on multiple lines in a label, but the array is bookended by parentheses and is separated by commas.

For example, if i have an NSDictionary key @"Cat" which has an NSArray value added to it like so: @"snow leopard", @"lion", @"tiger", then my output on screen will be the following:

```
(
snow leopard,
lion,
tiger
)
```

Is there a way to get rid of this punctuation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not really the purpose of the `description` method, what's implicitly being called to form that string. You should use the following:

```
[[self.dictionary selectList] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Which will take an array and join it with spaces between each item.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the tip! Is it possible to put a line break between the words?

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked - if you found the answer satisfactory, don't forget to mark it as "accepted."

Comment: Whoops I thought I'd accepted it already. It's definitely satisfactory .